# How to set log level in cfx

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I can't see my console.debug() messages when running

```
cfx run
```

Can I set a log level or a preference controlling it from [CFX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx) command line or some kind of confguration?

Comment: cfx's successor jpm has [--prefs key](http://work.erikvold.com/jetpack-pro-tip/2014/09/30/jpm-prefs.html) to set arbitrary options

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I've edited `addon-sdk-1.17/python-lib/cuddlefish/prefs.py` changing value of

```
'extensions.sdk.console.logLevel': 'info'
```

entry in DEFAULT_COMMON_PREFS object.